# React - Mapping out Components returning error

Tags: reactjs, meteor, react-router-dom

There is an app I would like to build with many pages, I figured the best way to do this would be to put all the pages name and path into a separate file and then mapping out each one as oppose to having a long list of components in render.  My only problem is that when I try to use the map function, it returns an error saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1`

**routes.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { withRouter, Switch, BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import Login from "../ui/authentication/Login";
import Signup from "../ui/authentication/Signup";
import Home from "../ui/Home";
import { SubjectRoutes } from "../ui/subjectRoutes/subjectRoutes";
import Math from "../ui/subjectRoutes/routes/math"
import Science from "../ui/subjectRoutes/routes/science"
import NotFound from "../ui/NotFound";

export default class Routes extends React.Component{
  renderSubjectRoutes(subjects){
    console.log(SubjectRoutes)
    return subjects.map((subject) => {
      return <{subject.name} path={subject.path} />
    })
  }
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Login path="/login" />
            <Signup path="/signup" />
            <Home path="/home"/>
            {this.renderSubjectRoutes(SubjectRoutes)}
            <NotFound />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**subjectRoutes.js**

```
export const SubjectRoutes = [{
  name: "Science",
  path: "/science"
},{
  name:"Math",
  path:"/math"
}]
```

I have also tried returning `<Route component={subject.name} path={subject.path}>`  but it returns a warning like `Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop component of type string supplied to Route, expected function.` Would you know any possible solutions to map out each route without having to do each one individually? Or is there some other better way to do this that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<Route component={subject.name} path={subject.path}>
```

doesn't work because your `subject.name` is a string (as is pointed out in the error). You need your route object to point to the actual components rather than its name in order to make it work.

**subjectRoutes.js**

```
import Math from "../ui/subjectRoutes/routes/math"
import Science from "../ui/subjectRoutes/routes/science"

export const SubjectRoutes = [{
  name: Science,
  path: "/science"
},{
  name:Math,
  path:"/math"
}]
```

Check out  [route configs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/route-config) of React Router where you can map data to components.